# Extract the address portion of a callers response

Tags: watson-conversation

In a conversation turn the caller is asked for the address of their destination.  A few response examples:

```
  I'm heading to 123 Lombard Street.
  I'll be at 2210 third Ave.
  I should be arriving to 44 Cross Terrace about 3:00 this afternoon.
```

Is it possible to isolate and extract the the address portion of the users response:

```
  123 Lombard Street
  2210 third Ave.
  44 Cross Terrace
```

I'm looking for advice, best practices on whether this extraction can be accomplished using intents and entities to locate the numeric portion, and (street, Ave, Terrace) portions and wild-card what's in between (Lombard, third., Cross) or will application code be required to locate and extract the address portion.

If any additional information is required I'll be happy to provide on request.

Answer (score 0):

A strategy could be to use the [system entity `@sys-number`](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-number) to point to the beginning of your referenced address snippets. The metadata for each found entity holds the location information (begin / end in the input string). From there you would need to search the input string for anything not in your specific "address vocabulary".

You could add your adress vocabulary (street, road, terrace, avenue plus the synonyms) as entities. The range from  smallest entity position to highest could be extracted and then used to normalize the address.

The extraction and some processing can be done inside the conversation service, but you likely need to have outside logic to normalize the found address snippets to what you need.

This blog entry about [tips & tricks for building chatbots](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/building-chatbots-tips-tricks/) has some useful stuff and links to a repository with some detailed examples of processing entities and variables.